# ¿Qué significa este error al compilar; "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [_fpermisive]"?

Tags: c++

Error:

> [error]ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [_fpermisive]

```
#include <iostream>
#define max 200
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct datos_club{
    char n_socio[8];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    char sector;
    int n_fila;
    int n_asiento;
    int antiguedad;

};

//prototipos
void leer_(datos_club A[],int n);
void mostrar_(datos_club A[],int n);
void Escribir_Socios(datos_club A[],int n);
int Buscar_Socios(datos_club A[],int n,int codigo);

//funcion principal
int main(){
    struct datos_club datos[max];

    int i;
    int n;
    char n_socios[8];
    int cod;

    cout<<"numero de personas: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"DATOS DE LOS SOCIOS\n\n";
    leer_(datos,n);
    cout<<"MOSTRAR DATOS DE SOCIO\n\n";
    mostrar_(datos,n);
    cout<<"Mostrando la persona que tiene una antiguedad mayor que 5\n\n";
    Escribir_Socios(datos,n);
    cout<<"ingrese codigo :";
    cin>>cod;
    Buscar_Socios(datos,n,cod);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

//definicion de funciones
void leer_(datos_club A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        cout<<"codigo de socio: ";
        cin>>A[i].n_socio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"nombre: ";
        cin.getline(A[i].nombre,20);
        cout<<"apellido: ";
        cin.getline(A[i].apellido,20);
        cout<<"sector t/p/f/g : ";
        cin>>A[i].sector;
        cout<<"n_fila: ";
        cin>>A[i].n_fila;
        cout<<"n_asiento: ";
        cin>>A[i].n_asiento;
        cout<<"antiguedad(años): ";
        cin>>A[i].antiguedad;
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }

}
void mostrar_(datos_club A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    cout<<"codigo del socio: "<<A[i].n_socio<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre: "<<A[i].nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"apellido: "<<A[i].apellido<<endl;
    cout<<"sector t/p/f/g : "<<A[i].sector<<endl;
    cout<<"n_filas: "<<A[i].n_fila<<endl;
    cout<<"n_asiento: "<<A[i].n_asiento<<endl;
    cout<<"antiguedad: "<<A[i].antiguedad<<endl<<endl;
    }
}



void Escribir_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].antiguedad>5){
            if(A[i].sector=='p'){
            cout<<"codigo del socio: "<<A[i].nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"apellido: "<<A[i].apellido<<endl;
            cout<<"n_fila: "<<A[i].n_fila<<endl;
            cout<<"n_asiento: "<<A[i].n_asiento<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}   

int Buscar_Socios (struct datos_club socios[],int n, int codigo){

    bool band=false;
    int w=0;
    do{
        if (codigo==socios[w].n_socio && band!=true){<--aca me sale ese mensaje
        return 1;
        band=true;  
        }
        else {
            return 0;
            w++;
        }
    }while (w<n);

}
```

Comment: por favor copia bien tu código, sigue las instrucciones

Answer (score 3):

Significa que en este fragmento de código:

```
codigo == socios[w].n_socio
```

Estás comparando un entero (`código`) con una cadena (`socios[w].n_socio`), esto no es correcto ya que un array decae en un puntero cuando aplicamos el operador `==`, lo que resulta en comparar un entero con una dirección de memória, antes debes transformar la cadena a un entero:

```
codigo == (int)strtol(socios[w].n_socio, NULL, 10)
```